# Download base 64 as tiff file

Tags: javascript, tiff

I'm having a base64 string which I will have to download to client as tiff using javascript how do i achieve this?
I tried

```
window.open("data:application/tiff;base64," + base64data + '');
```

Please assist me with this...

Comment: And what happened when you tried that?

Comment: Is your base64 data in a tiff file format?